# Putnam on Jewish philosophy

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy

[Hillary Putnam](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilary_Putnam), one of the greatest philosophers of all time, wrote at least one book on Jewish philosophy: [Jewish Philosophy as a Guide to Life:
Rosenzweig, Buber, Levinas, Wittgenstein](http://www.iupress.indiana.edu/product_info.php?products_id=76824). I was wondering if someone could summarize his ideas in a paragraph or two.

Comment: From the Amazon review: In spite of the major differences among the thinkers he discusses, Putnam finds they have in common a commitment to experiential philosophy. "Experiential Philosophy" is itself difficult to understand. It involves a rejection of essentialism -- that is of traditional philosophical speculation -- and a commitment to philosophy as narrative in a face-to-face discussion with other human beings about what is important in life. Religion, for the philosphers Putnam discusses, is to be lived from the inside, from felt experience, rather than studied through abstractions.

Comment: The full review can be found here: https://www.amazon.com/review/R1QD8M4ZRF4UBF/ref=cm_cr_dp_title?ie=UTF8&ASIN=0253351332&channel=detail-glance&nodeID=283155&store=books

Comment: Interesting, on what Wittgenstein is linked to Jewish Philosophy? Seems very exciting.